# setPermissions on files using SkyDrive API

Tags: onedrive

We would like to interface our cloud app with storage on user's SkyDrive. Has anyone worked out how to emulate sharing with the SkyDrive API. As far as I can tell it's not supported in the public API apis.live.net/v5.0 but of course the SkyDrive site itself is doing this using an API call like;

```
POST https://skydrive.live.com/API/2/SetPermissions
...
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
...
{"id":"F2720F142345635B!207","entities":[{"role":2,"type":0,"email":"someuser@somedomain.com"}],"requireSignIn":true,"userAction":0}:
```

As far as I can tell, this isn't what happens when we use the JavaScript API `wl.api()` Is `skydrive.live.com/api` OK to use or would this be an unsupported/illegal hack? I would dearly love a contact on the SkyDrive team to give an official response on this.

Answer (score 1):

The API does provide a way to get a unique link to the file for reading or editing

GET https://apis.live.netv5.0/file.a6b2a7e8f2515e5e.A6B2A7E8F2515E5E!126
/shared_read_link?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

or

GET https://apis.live.netv5.0/file.a6b2a7e8f2515e5e.A6B2A7E8F2515E5E!126/shared_edit_link?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

Comment: Sure, but the question is regarding changing permissions on the resource the way the skydrive site does. Those shared read links (as returned from the wl.api() don't allow sharing with a specific email address.

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty disappointed with this limitation. The work around that I am considering involves using this link and presenting it to the shared user as a regular file. Once they click the link and edit the file, a share permission is established. It's ok for files since it directs the user to the word/excel app but for folders it just directs them to skydrive which is not ideal for a smooth user experience.

Comment: The downside is that the link isn't specifically tied to a user email or account. Basically, it's just the first person to use the token AFAIK. So if you share it with dave@acme.com but they click on the link logging in using another account, say (dave@gmail.com) then the permissions will be assigned to the "wrong" account. It doesn't even have to be the same person of course. The unfortunate thing is that if your intention was to share with dave@acme.com email account you have no real guarantee (or hint) that they'll use that account. It's annoying because the private API clearly supports it.